# why does this code take a long time in R?

Tags: r

#why does this code take a long time in R?

```
k<-1000
dat <- NULL
for (x in 0:k){
 for (j in 0:k){ 
    Y <- ((x + j)/2)
     dat <- rbind(dat,x,j,Y) 
    }
  }
out <- list(dat=dat)
```

Comment: This is not the way to program in R ~ nested loops and without preallocation. Most operations in R are vectorized, try to utilize that fact when ever you construct code.

Comment: Also are you sure you want `rbind(dat,x,j,Y)` which puts all the values (`x`, `j` and `Y`) in the same column ?

Comment: Your code is slow because it resides in the 2nd and 3rd circle of the R-inferno. https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: You probably want `dat = expand.grid(x = 0:k, j = 0:k); dat$Y = with(dat, (x + j) / 2)`. Note, even if you are from `c++`, you would want to allocate your out vector ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a benchmark of some approaches.  I have modified the code in the question to what I think you want. You may wish to repeat it for some other values of k.

```
library(microbenchmark)

k <- 2

microbenchmark(
ques = {
  res_q <- NULL
  for (x in 0:k){
    for (j in 0:k){ 
      Y <- ((x + j)/2)
      res_q <- rbind(res_q, c(x, j, Y)) 
    } 
  }
  res_q
},
expand.grid = {
  g <- expand.grid(x = 0:k, j = 0:k)[2:1]
  res_g <- as.matrix(transform(g, Y = (x + j) / 2))
  dimnames(res_g) <- NULL
  res_g
},
rep = {
  res_r <- cbind(x = rep(x = 0:k, each = k+1), j = 0:k, Y = NA)
  res_r[, "Y"] <- rowSums(res_r[, 1:2]) / 2
  dimnames(res_r) <- NULL
  res_r
})
## Unit: microseconds
##         expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq     max neval cld
##         ques 28829.2 29268.00 30493.273 29712.45 30303.5 56836.1   100   c
##  expand.grid  1719.3  1784.85  1892.908  1882.70  1917.1  3706.7   100  b 
##          rep    70.3    81.55   114.655   118.00   137.9   212.6   100 a
```

We verify that all approaches gave the same result:

```
all.equal(res_q, res_g, res_r)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Why is expand grid so less efficient? And can we patch base R?

Comment: We can make the `expand.grid` run twice as fast by not converting it to a matrix (which we did so the result would be identical to the rest) and using   `res_g$Y <- with(g, (x + j) / 2)` in place of `transform` ; however, the `rep` solution will still be nearly 10x faster on the data shown even with those performance improvements.